# Jquery does not select the option the second time around

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this very weird occurence of JQuery not selecting the select option when opening the modal the second time around. Basically, I have a table that displays an edit modal when clicking on the row. The modal contains input textboxes and select controls. Upon page load, the select controls are being populated from the database using php.

```
<select id="subitemstatuse" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($statusdata2 as $key => $value): ?>
         <option value='<?php echo trim($value["statusid"])?>'><?php echo $value["statusname"] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

It works normally when I click ANY row the first time, modal gets displayed with correct values selected in the select option. BUT when the modal gets hidden and the select controls are reset, clicking the same row (or any other row) does not correctly show the selected option anymore.

```
var selectedrow = document.getElementById("tablesubitembody").rows[rowNum];
$("#subitemstatuse option[value='"+ selectedrow.cells[6].innerText.trim() +"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Inspecting the source, it puts the attribute "SELECTED" to the Correct option, but it only shows the first option instead. I have tried using setTimeout function but still, the same issue occurs. BTW, im using google chrome.

Comment: Are you using a select plugin at all, like `bootstrap-select` etc..? If so, which one specifically?

Comment: Can you create a working [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com) for this?